Trying to download Next.Js but keep getting error "Cannot find Module"
Trying to download Next.Js but keep getting error "Cannot find Module" enter image description here
Could any one help please? Time sensitive
I tried re installing node js but it still did not work and created a new npm folder inside roaming-> App Data

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

this is an issue with npx installation, it looks like you have a wrong path which you can fix via environment variables, see solution here - NPM: npm-cli.js not found when running npm
